# WCF error Operation is not valid for state of transaction

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2014, transactionscope

On MSDTC, I have created a transaction-enabled service but it gives an error:

> the operation is not valid for the state of a transaction

Below is the Server stack trace:

> ```
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionChannel1.WriteTransactionToMessage(Message message, TransactionFlowOption txFlowOption)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionChannel1.WriteTransactionDataToMessage(Message message, MessageDirection direction)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionRequestChannelGeneric1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
> ```

Comment: Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. At least post some source code - as it this is likely to be voted to be closed.

Comment: Please provide some code or more details, what you said is not enough to judge the problem.